# Web P2P video confrence solution

Tags: flash, video, streaming, p2p, conference

I'm looking for the best possible solution which will allow me to incorporate live video/audio conference between 2 users(only 2 at this point) into a flash gaming platform.
The video chat is not just an extra feature, it's the main one.

I'm mainly looking at open source implementations or something I'll be able to implement myself, but will consider commercial products if they are exactly what I need.

Here are a few things I've looked at, but so far, I didn't find any of them good enough:

1. Flash player 10's P2P capabilities
   sound promising, but I am aware of
   the fact that Adobe has not release
   any information on the RTMFP
   protocol and that there is no
   commercial server which supports it
   at this point.
2. Stream all the
   video/audio live through a flash
   server (not p2p), but from my
   personal experience you don't get a
   smooth conversation.
   I think [TokBox](http://tokbox.com/) uses this method
3. Java applets are a possible solution
   too (to perform p2p), but I don't
   think it will be a nice and elegant
   solution to combine them in the game
   at this point (and requires the user
   to authorize them). BTW, I couldn't find any useful implementations. So, If you know of any, i'll look into them.
4. Google Gmail Video Chat uses a
   custom (and proprietary) browser
   plug-in which does the p2p and
   streams the video/audio into the
   flash player. This is a possible
   solution, but I rather not implement
   the entire p2p protocol stack +
   browser plug-in at this stage and
   concentrate on other aspect of the
   game itself.  I think they are using XMPP based protocol similar to [Jingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29) and they've release a [Jingle librarby](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) but without the video confrencing implementation.
5. **EDIT:** In response to Branden:
   I am aware of Adobe Stratus. Stratus
   is a beta, hosted rendezvous service
   that aids establishing
   communications between Flash Player
   endpoints (RTMFP server).
   This
   current release of the Stratus is
   prerelease and is designed for
   evaluation purposes only. The
   service is not final.
   There is no
   guarantee that the service will
   continue to exist in the future or
   any information about the future
   cost.
   That's why I don't think
   it can be used as a commercial
   solution. At least not yet.

I'd appreciate your suggestions and advice. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The server in question is currently called Stratus. You can find out more about it at [Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/).
2. You can absolutely get smooth streaming with a server-based solution with Flash, but you have to have enough bandwidth to support all of the streams (4 streams for a two person conversation - 2 up and to down). There are a few options here, but the two best are probably [Adobe's Flash Media Interactive Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediainteractive/) and the opensource (and quite awesome) [Red5](http://www.red5server.org/).
3. I agree that an applet-based solution would be inelegant, but it may be the only real way to get p2p video at this time.
4. Jingle is very cool, but as you mentioned the open source bits don't support video yet. I don't think re-implementing it is a really viable solution only because of the level of effort required.

Comment: Branden, thanks for your reply
1. See edit in regards to Stratus
2. I haven't experimented with Red5, as I was looking for a p2p solution. I am aware of it and am considering using it or another Flash Socket server that allows flash Streaming like ElectroServer

Comment: In my experience ElectroServer scaled up really well and did a great job with data, but it had some issues with video streams - but this was about a year ago. Red5 ended up being the solution I went with. We didn't need it's origin/edge-based setup for our project, but I hear it can be used to scale things up quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe's [LiveCycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/collaborationservice/) is a commercial implementation of Stratus. You [pay](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2775152) on a per use basis.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm late to the party on this one, but Frozen Mountain (whom I work for) has a product out now called [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/products/icelink) that'll do what you want. It'll use native WebRTC when the browser supports it, and fall back to a Java applet.

In response to the specific questions you asked:

1. RTMFP: Yep, proprietary communications is no fun. Bummer that they haven't opened the spec.
2. Non-P2P definitely takes a performance hit. Also, scalability becomes an issue.
3. Java applets are the only way to get pure UDP ports when the browser doesn't have native WebRTC, which is the route we took.
4. Custom plugins are rough, on multiple fronts, as you noted. Java applets aren't great, but at least it's not a whole download/install process :)

Hope that helps a little!